# Can the following query may cause a deadlock for concurrent transactions?

Tags: php, mysql

Executing this query may cause deadlock ? If yes, then please explain how??

```
  $q="UPDATE SET `count` =`count` + 1 WHERE user_id='$uid' FOR UPDATE";
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not cause a deadlock. Even if a lot of queries try to update at the same time, they will either wait for the other query to finish the update. Or Mysql optimiser will run them simultaneously if different queries are updating different rows, given that you are using InnoDB engine. In MyISAM, there is only table-level locking so the queries will end up running sequentially even if they are run at the same time.

I do not see why there will be a deadlock with this query.